# Get from column A the elements from the same row of B with the index taken from C

Tags: google-sheets, filtering

In the [table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ytYJNoJg1SgXSQDm0egHmD01klOv5-0PgTmP0LDEhg8/edit?usp=sharing) depicted below, I want to do what the question title says:

> In column F, put elements from the same row of B where A has same indice taken from (E sorted by D)

I'm quite inexperienced with Google Sheets and suppose this is simple, but I'm a bit lost.

[image]

Comment: you got sheet for that too for sharing?

Comment: Added link at the beginning of question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try **`VLOOKUP`** for that. paste it in **F2** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E2:E; A2:B; 2; 0); ))
```

Answer (score 1):

also you can just use extended range in **`FILTER`** formula in **E2** cell:

```
=FILTER(A2:B; C2:C > 0)
```